# Going out of scope prematurely

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a scenario where an `Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<()>>` is used to serialize an operation(as it doesn't support concurrent processing). I am running into an issue where the MutexGuard sometimes gets dropped before the end of scope, causing undefined behavior as the assumption is violated. This is with tokio 0.2.22

I've tried to capture the issue here: [play ground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d95a2fb461c618f5623e2423856fa003). Though this toy example would run as expected, the issue manifests in a very small number of cases under load in the deployed code.

Questions:

1. My understanding is that rust guarantees objects to be freed at the end of scope. Or is this not true? Are there cases where this may not be true
2. Could this caused by the old tokio version in play here?

Comment: I see no possible way the code you posted could exhibit the described behavior.

Comment: OK, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54716. This indeed appears to be the problem. Tried replacing `tokio::task::spawn_blocking()` with a direct call (as experiment), that appears to fix it

Comment: Are you using an old unstable version of Rust? Because that issue pertains to the state of affairs in pre-stable `async` back in 2019, and does not appear relevant to today

Comment: I am using cargo 1.45.1, tokio 0.2.22

Answer (score -2):

> My understanding is that rust guarantees objects to be freed at the end of scope. Or is this not true? Are there cases where this may not be true

This is not true, and yes the compiler can decide to drop things long before the end of scope if it's considered unused. A common case is creating a drop-able object and never binding it to anything: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e10235743daca5b1286577b7d94a9af7

This would be much more likely in async functions if you're binding but not *using* variables across suspension points (`await`), because the code is compiled to a state machine repeatedly calling a single function. If the transformation doesn't see your variable being used after the suspension point, it might not store the item in the Future object, therefore the item will be dropped *at* the suspension point, which is in essence an end-of-scope.

> Could this caused by the old tokio version in play here?

Don't see why, tokio doesn't control `async`'s codegen, so it would not influence drop locations.

Comment: The compiler cannot "decide to drop things before the end of scope". `Drop::drop` is always called at the end of the smallest enclosing scope (in reverse order of declaration). It is true that the "smallest enclosing scope" *may* be only one line, but the compiler does not have the ability to make a *decision* and whether the thing is *unused* or not has nothing to do with it; it's just a matter of how scopes work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `async` functions work in this respect; however, if it does work as you seem to imply, count me surprised -- can the compiler actually call `Drop::drop` early on a value that hasn't gone out of scope yet because it's in an `async` function? Can you provide an example of this behavior or point to some documentation that evidences it?

Comment: [PR #60437](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/60437) and comments on [the issue OP linked in the question comments](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54716) seem to agree with my "intuitive" read wrt `async fn`, although apparently it wasn't always this way